# efficient way to operate on JSON type file

Tags: python, json, mongodb, data-analysis, bigdata

So, I have a JSON file something which is a large one and keep on increasing.
So, I am showing a simpler version here.

```
{
"b0:47:bf:af:c1:42": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 10, "cities": 
    {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 5,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 3,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
},
"c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 24, "cities": 
    {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 20,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
  }
}
```

So, basically it contains information about a id which is basically mac_address `b0:47:bf:af:c1:42` and related to one user. So, what I want is to operate on JSON and store the output in data frame type of structure.

Like I want to know user's max visited city and %of his/her total visit to max_visited city.

So,I want a output like this for above data.

```
mac_address             max_vis city        %visit to max_vis city
b0:47:bf:af:c1:42       Mumbai              50%
k0:k0:k0:k0:k0:k0       Kolkata             83%
```

What kind tool o should use to do this kind of operation on JSON simply and efficiently. I have heard MongoDB can be used for this but I have no idea about that. earlier I was trying to do this in python is there a efficient way to do it in python either?So, if anyone can suggest me what should I use and give some basics to start with that will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: You can use `json` module for python to parse file, but I don't really understand what is your question.

Comment: @PatrykPerduta parsing is fine look what I have as input and what is desired output `count` is no. of times he visited city

Comment: You ask us to create whole solution for you?

Comment: @PatrykPerduta as I mentioned this is just a small part of whole problem and not solution, "So, if anyone can suggest me what should I use and give some basics to start with that will be very helpful." as I ended quesiton with this lines.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. How big is file you need to analyze? You have some solution already and it's too slow, or you're just estimating this as to be slow because file is big?

Comment: Well I have Iterated a data frame into this JSON (or dict) which takes a lot of time in running. Now I dont want to again iterate to get back my desired data frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115701/discussion-between-patryk-perduta-and-ranadan).

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? It uses the standard json module. https://ideone.com/U6B1uC

Comment: @Goodies yes kind of but you are not storing it in data frame right?

Comment: It's using only standard libraries.

Comment: @Goodies  yes thanx, can you please store the output in data frame rather printing?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You should be capable of taking what's there and converting it. Although if you are using pandas, you can read the JSON directly.

Comment: @Goodies okay no problem :), yes I am using pandas and I can read the JSON directly thanx.

Comment: @Goodies like you did `max(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'])`  is there a simple way to sum the count and get the result ?

Answer (score 1):

You implement like this. It's implement with the basic dictionary operations. The concept is created a list of list with the no.of visit and city name. And it's sorted with using key `itemgetter`. Get the max visited city from there and get the percent with simple math operations.

```
from operator import itemgetter
for key,value in main_dict.items():
    sorted_list = sorted([[val['count'],key1] for key1,val in value['cities'].items()],key=itemgetter(0))[-1]
    print [key,sorted_list[1],str(round(float(sorted_list[0])/float(value['No. of visits'])*100,2))+' %']
```

**Result**

```
['b0:47:bf:af:c1:42', 'Mumbai', '50.0 %']
['c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d', 'Kolkata', '83.33 %']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json` library in Python. It takes a string, and gives back a `dict` which you can then parse.

While I have no disagreement with Rahul's answer, I think it's neater to use the max function instead, and the basic data structure from the json.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
# You load this however you want. 
the_string = """{
"b0:47:bf:af:c1:42": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 10, "cities": 
    {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 5,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 3,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
},
"c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 24, "cities": 
    {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 20,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
  }
}"""

print('{:20} {:20s} {:20s}'.format('mac_addr' , 'max_vis_city', '% visits' ))

json_object = json.loads(the_string, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
for item in list(json_object):
    max_value = max (json_object[item]["cities"], key=lambda k: json_object[item]["cities"][k]["count"])
    print('{:20s} {:20s} {:<20.0f}'.format(item, max_value, round(json_object[item]["cities"][max_value]["count"]/json_object[item]["No. of visits"] * 100)))
```

Output:

```
mac_addr             max_vis_city         % visits
b0:47:bf:af:c1:42    Mumbai               50
c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d    Kolkata              83
```